# Add RadioButton from a Java-generated ListView to a RadioGroup

Tags: java, android, listview

How can I add a radio from a listview button to a radioGroup?

**This is the code of the OnItemClick**

```
  lvSearchResult.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                    long id) {
                final HashMap<String, String> item =  (HashMap<String, String>) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                final RadioButton rbAddITem = (RadioButton)parent.getChildAt(position).findViewById(R.id.rbAddItem_Radio);      
                String searchQuery = item.get("ProductName").toString();
                if(rbAddITem.isChecked()){
                    rbAddITem.setChecked(false);
                }else{
                    rbAddITem.setChecked(true);
                }   
            }
        });

    }
```

Thank you very Much for the help.

Comment: Your code suggests you are checking/unchecking a checkbox. I don't see any code to add a radio button? Am I missing something?